# Map the value of a new column by searching another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, mapping, fips

I have two dataframes: `df_geo` and `df_event`. I want to create two new columns in `df_event`.  The data frames resemble the following, although additional columns have been removed for the sake of simplicity:

```
data_geo =  [['040','01','000','00000','00000','00000','Alabama'],
             ['050','01','001','00000','00000','00000','Autauga County'],
             ['050','01','097','00000','00000','00000','Mobile County'],
             ['050','01','101','00000','00000','00000','Montgomery County'],
             ['050','01','115','00000','00000','00000','St. Clair County'],
             ['040','09','000','00000','00000','00000','Connecticut'],
             ['061','09','001','04720','00000','00000','Bethel town'],
             ['040','17','000','00000','00000','00000','Illinois'],
             ['061','17','109','05638','00000','00000','Bethel township'],
             ['050','17','163','00000','00000','00000','St. Clair County']] 

dfgeo = pd.DataFrame(data_geo, columns = ['summary_level', 'state_fips','county_fips','subdivision_code_fips','place_code_fips','city_code_fips','area_name']) 

df_geo.info()

RangeIndex: 43847 entries, 0 to 43846
Data columns (total 7 columns):
summary_level            43847 non-null object
state_fips               43847 non-null object
county_fips              43847 non-null object
subdivision_code_fips    43847 non-null object
place_code_fips          43847 non-null object
city_code_fips           43847 non-null object
area_name                43847 non-null object
```

```
data_event = [['event_id','_','Alabama'], 
              ['event_id','_','Connecticut'],
              ['event_id','Autauga County','Alabama'],
              ['event_id','Fairfield County','Connecticut'],
              ['event_id','Fairbanks North Star Borough','Alaska']] 

df_event = pd.DataFrame(data_event, columns = ['event_id','county','state']) 

df_event.info()

RangeIndex: 1261 entries, 0 to 1260
Data columns (total 3 columns):
event_id                1261 non-null object
county                   999 non-null object
state                   1261 non-null object
dtypes: object(3)
```

**GOAL** to create a function that can take the `county` and `state` inputs from `df_event` and in order to create two new columns in the same dataframe.  The new columns are based on the values of `state_fips` and `county_fips` in `df_geo`.  An example of this would look like the following:

```
inputA fun('df_geo','Connecticut','Fairfield County'):   

resultA = ['event_id','Connecticut','Fairfield County','09','001']
                                                       ^New columns

inputB fun('df_geo','Alaska','Fairbanks North Star Borough'):   

resultB = ['event_id','Alaska','Fairbanks North Star Borough','02','090']
                                                              ^New columns
```

This is a **PROBLEM** because I also need to use this function on a list of 1,200 (and growing) events the function would have to work within a lamba function or something else that can map it across the entire dataframe.

This is complicated by identical County names like "St. Clair County" that appear in several states.  Although their `area_names` are identical the value of `state_fips` will be different.

The `state_fips` of St. Clair Illinois is **17**, the same as all other counties in Illinois and the state itself.  The `state_fips` of St. Clair Alabama is **01**, the same as all other counties in Alabama, and so on...

I would like to use the same search and map function all the way down to `city_code_fips`.  At that level any search terms have to be exactly the same to avoid picking up "Bethel town" when I intend to find "Bethel township".  Exact inputs are also important because some states, like Louisiana, call their *county* level geographies by another name.

In `df_event` a '_' indicates that the county is unknown.

`df_event['event_id']` is a unique string.  There are rows in the dataframe that are nearly identical but with different ids indicating that an event has occurred on multiple occasions.  This has no affect on the. `state_fips` or `county_fips`.

I know this is a multi step process but all help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: The problem is complicated by identical county names that exist in multiple states (Lancaster County, King County, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using [`df.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
In [289]: df_event['state_fips'] = df_event.merge(dfgeo[['state_fips','area_name']], left_on='state', right_on='area_name', how='left')['state_fips']    
In [290]: df_event['county_fips'] = df_event.merge(dfgeo[['county_fips','area_name']], left_on='county', right_on='area_name', how='left')['county_fips']

In [291]: df_event
Out[291]: 
  unique_str                        county        state state_fips county_fips
0   Event Id                             _      Alabama         01         NaN
1   Event Id                             _  Connecticut         09         NaN
2   Event Id                Autauga County      Alabama         01         001
3   Event Id              Fairfield County  Connecticut         09         001
4   Event Id  Fairbanks North Star Borough       Alaska         02         090
```

Comment: @MayankPorwal so it runs but it the `county_fips` is for index 0 is appearing in index 1, index 1 in index2, but the pattern isn't consistent.  In some `df_event`rows where `county` is not provided a `county_fips` is returned.

Comment: @MayankPorwal The code runs but does not return matching fips.  I have included a link to two images.  One is a output of the function and the other is head of `df_geo`. You can see there are rows like Mobile County that should be "01" "097" but are instead returning "01" "113" in some places but correct results in others.
https://photos.app.goo.gl/pTEeXExpHR7uyFwG8
https://photos.app.goo.gl/uYaXz36rePHVn2yj9

Answer (score 0):

If there are duplicates in use `area_name` column first remove them by [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
dfgeo = dfgeo.drop_duplicates('area_name')
```

And then [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html), what is faster like `merge`, so it should be preferable:

```
df_event['state_fips'] = df_event['state'].map(dfgeo.set_index('area_name')['state_fips'])
df_event['county_fips'] = df_event['county'].map(dfgeo.set_index('area_name')['county_fips'])
print (df_event)
  unique_str                        county        state state_fips county_fips
0   Event Id                             _      Alabama         01         NaN
1   Event Id                             _  Connecticut         09         NaN
2   Event Id                Autauga County      Alabama         01         001
3   Event Id              Fairfield County  Connecticut         09         001
4   Event Id  Fairbanks North Star Borough       Alaska         02         090
```

Comment: I received the following error:  "InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects"

Comment: @Drew111 - It means there are duplicated values in `df` after `melt`, because duplicated values in `dfgeo`.

Comment: So you need remove duplicates, e.g. by `dfgeo = dfgeo.drop_duplicates('area_name')` before my solution.

Comment: I will reset and try again but running dfgeo.info() before and after returned the following changes to the dataframe:
```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 43847 entries, 0 to 43846

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 25888 entries, 0 to 43846
```

Comment: @Drew111 - Answer was changed, can you test now?

Comment: @Drew111 - So it means there is a lot of duplicates?

Comment: I am getting the same error.  Would it help to upload an screenshot of the Traceback?

Comment: @Drew111 - hmm, it is weird, because `drop_duplicates` remove duplicates, but be free show me picture

Comment: @jezarel I think deleting duplicates may be part of the problem as there are many rows in `dfgeo` with the same names on purpose.  

Each state and county has a unique identifier `state_fips`, or `county_fips`.  Many counties in US have the same `area_name` but no state can have counties with the same`area_name`, similar to how the US doesnt have any states with the same name.

https://photos.app.goo.gl/xNxsgW4HyRtmtMt1A
https://photos.app.goo.gl/TgzW6ZsV9Hh8XcD96